# Bound gridview problem; jquery resolution in unbind?

Tags: jquery, data-binding, gridview

Good evening all.

I have a bit of a puzzler for you.

On my page I have a cascading ddl (ddlBuyer), a textbox search (tbxProdAC) and a radio button list (radTopx). These, once populated, and a submit button clicked, produces a gridview populated with data. What I am trying to achieve is that the user can only select either the ddl, the textbox or the radiobutton list as a method for producing the gridview data.

I have achieved this, ish, by writing a bit of jquery syntax that essentially 'clears' the gridview and resets the different search methods, for example.

```
<code>
    ddlBuyer.Attributes.Add("onclick", 
    "$('#tbxProdAC').val(''); 
    $('#txtbxHowMany').val(''); 
    $('#GridView1').remove(); 
    $('#radTopx input').attr('checked',false); 
    $('#radProd').attr('checked', false);");
</code>
```

However, because this is occurring client side, the server side events (i.e. ddlBuyer_SelectedIndexChanged) are still being executed and subsequently, the data is being bound when I don't really want it to. i.e. if I select the radtopx button, click the button to produce the gridview (this occurring on a postback).

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    if (radTopx.SelectedValue == "" || txtbxHowMany.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Ensure that BOTH 'The Number of Products' and Appropriate material Is selected Before You Attempt To Run a TOP x Report", "Top x Error!!!",
             MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        GridView1.DataSourceID = null;
    }

    else
    {
        int max = 0;
        if (int.TryParse(txtbxHowMany.Text, out max))
        {

            GridView1.DataSource = this.GetMaterialData(Session["MemberKey"].ToString(), radTopx.SelectedItem.Value, "Primary", max);
            GridView1.DataSourceID = String.Empty;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

I then click on ddlBuyer, the radTopx information is cleared but the gridview  is retained as the following is fired:

rotected void ddlBuyer_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ORDataClassesDataContext dbII = new ORDataClassesDataContext();
        var queryII = (from r in dbII.tblOnlineReportingFINALPRODUCTs
                       where r.UnitUserfield1 == ddlBuyer.SelectedValue
                       select new { UnitUserfield2 = r.UnitUserfield2 }).Distinct().OrderBy(r => r.UnitUserfield2);

```
    ddlSub.DataSource = queryII;
    ddlSub.DataTextField = "UnitUserfield2";
    ddlSub.DataValueField = "UnitUserfield2";
    ddlSub.DataBind();
    ddlSub.Items.Insert(0, "--Choose Sub Category--");

    GridView1.DataSourceID = null;
```

Is there a way to 'unbind' the grid view through jquery so that when ddlBuyer is clicked, the gridview has released any data it may have previously held?

Apologies if this doesn't make sense, it is a bit difficult to describe succinctly and accurately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds interesting MrDean. I've had similar experience trying to unbind events that were previously bound by something else and it can be a bit of a noodle-scratcher. Without seeing an example of what your elements look like (as HTML) it's difficult to know how these events are bound.

If they are bound by simply populating the `onclick` attribute of each element, this one is quite easy to undo.

```
$('.myElement').attr('onclick', ''); //Empty out the onclick attribute
$('.myElement').bind('click', function(){ ... }); //Bind your own function to the click event
```

You'll find it's a much better idea to bind your function using the DOM rather than manipulating attributes of individual elements. It's much more flexible and there's a lot more you can do with it.

Now, if your original functions are bound using the DOM method rather than manipulating the `onclick` attribute things get a little trickier. The first thing you could try is to go:

```
$('.myElement').unbind();
```

which will make jQuery unbind all events associated with a given element. Where this gets tricky is figuring out when to call `unbind()`. If you do it on `ready` and the other library executes its `ready` function after yours, then you've achieved nothing because the events haven't been bound yet.

Give this a try and let me know how you go. Failing that, please upload the HTML of the page you are trying to manipulate and I'll take a look.

Hope this helps!

Cheers

Iain

Comment: Hello Iain. Thank you very much for replying and taking the out to have a look at this little scenario for me.

I've actually managed to fool my web application...when a user selects either the drop down, text box or radio button list, a postback is made.

I therefore just did a cop out and bound the gridview to a null datasource at this point..therefore, when the page is refreshsed, nothing wil be present in the gridview. A nice little cheat!

However, I will have a play with the above as it is quite interesting.

Thank you again.

Comment: I might be coming back to you Iain!!! This is driving me mad again...using my cheat caused the sorting/paging in my gridview to fail so I am going to give you method a go.

Comment: Cool mate, let me know how you go and if I can be of any assistance. If you get stuck, strip out everything but the bits that are causing you problems and upload a demo somewhere and I'll take a butchers.

Cheers mate
Iain